# Updating Android Listview Constantly but Retain onClick functionality

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am creating a timer in each Listview view but when I call notifyDataSetChange() constantly, I am unable to click my buttons.

Is there a way to retain button and editText functionality inside a listview view when updated constantly. Is there any alternatives?

Thanks!

UPDATE: This is the code I am running to update continously

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(runnable);

}
Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        adapterWhiteMales.notifyDataSetChanged();
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500);
    }
};
```

UPDATE: My buttons in each listview view
Didn't put all my code for the getChildView and button on click, but this is the main setup.

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parentView)
{
   if (view == null) {

        viewHolderItem = new ViewHolderItem();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_explistview_child_meet_athletes, parentView, false);
        viewHolderItem.btnStartLap = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnStartLap);

        view.setTag(viewHolderItem);
    } else {
        // Use already initialized variables
        viewHolderItem = (ViewHolderItem) view.getTag();
    }
   viewHolderItem.btnStartLap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()      
   {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("", "Start Lap Button Clicked!");
            }
   }

}
```

Comment: notifyDataSetChange is going to regenerate the views based on the data set. The problem may lie where you are setting the onClick listeners for the buttons. Can you share that portion of the code?

Comment: Sure, I'll update it in a minute

Comment: Updated it so you can see my setup for my getchildviews

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling that code in UI thread? Task could be pausing UI thread. Try using code below

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        notifyDataSetChange();
    }
});
```

Comment: I posted what I am running

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue in one of my apps where if I tried to set the onClick listener multiple times it would break the listener and cause weird behavior.

Try changing your getChildView method like so

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parentView)
{
    if (view == null) {

        viewHolderItem = new ViewHolderItem();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_explistview_child_meet_athletes, parentView, false);
        viewHolderItem.btnStartLap = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnStartLap);
        viewHolderItem.btnStartLap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()      
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("", "Start Lap Button Clicked!");
            }
        }
        view.setTag(viewHolderItem);
    } else {
        // Use already initialized variables
        viewHolderItem = (ViewHolderItem) view.getTag();
    }
}
```

Comment: No such luck. The problem is that I am notifying my adapter a datachange every 250ms so I am wondering if there is a way to not recreate my buttons every time. My buttons are unresponsive due to the notifydatachange every 250ms. Thanks!

Comment: We'll that's part of the problem, ListViews aren't meant to be rebuilt 4 times a second. That's a good way to drain the battery. If you want those kind of frequent updates you're going to want to look into OpenGL and game development techniques. I would suggest dropping the update to 5000 ms temporarily and seeing if that solves the problem.