# Updating Listview Continuosly Renders Buttons Useless

Tags: android, listview

I scoured the internet yesterday and today for a better solution to this, but couldn't find one.
I tried using a chronometer in my getViews, but they reset after expand/collapse or scroll.
I tried to store the times of the chronometers in my athlete objects, but the RecyclerView problem still occurred.

**Problem:**

Basically, I am trying to create ListViews which have start/stop/reset Buttons and a timer which appears in a TextView.
As of now, I am constantly calling `notifyDatasetChanged()`.
The problem is that unless I tone down my refresh rate to like 500ms, the Buttons take 2-3 times to click before working.

I am currently running a stopwatch specific to each athlete so as long as I stay on the same Fragment, each athletes timer is specific to each athlete and they run perfectly.
This is due to the fact that the screen updates quickly and gets each athletes stopwatch time every 500ms.
The problem with toning down the refresh rate to 500ms is that my timers then display every .5 seconds, which then looks bad.

Any solutions to make my buttons more responsive.

Fragment: (Refreshing listview)

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(runnable);

}
Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        adapterWhiteMales.notifyDataSetChanged();
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 250);
    }
};
```

GetChildView: (my custom adapter)

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parentView)
{

    final ViewHolderItem viewHolderItem;
    final listViewParentAthlete parent = parents.get(groupPosition);
    final Athlete athlete = parent.getChildren().get(childPosition);

    int viewType = getGroupType(groupPosition);

        // If child view has never been created, initialize variables
        if (view == null) {

            viewHolderItem = new ViewHolderItem();
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_explistview_child_meet_athletes, parentView, false);

            viewHolderItem.childSplitTimes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSplitTime);
            viewHolderItem.btnStartLap = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnStartLap);
            viewHolderItem.btnStop = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
            viewHolderItem.btnReset = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnReset);
            viewHolderItem.btnSave = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
            viewHolderItem.txtStopWatch = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtStopWatch);

            view.setTag(viewHolderItem);
        } else {
            // Use already initialized variables
            viewHolderItem = (ViewHolderItem) view.getTag();
        }

        // If you click the Start/Lap button, it starts the timer and adds splits
        viewHolderItem.btnStartLap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("", "Start Lap Button Clicked!");
                if (athlete.getEvents().get(finalEventPosition).getIsRunning() == false) {
                    Log.e("", "StopWatch Started!");
                    athlete.getEvents().get(finalEventPosition).startStopWatch();
                }
            }
        });
        // If you click the Stop/Reset button, it stops all times and last split. Working
        viewHolderItem.btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e("", "Stop Button Clicked!");
                athlete.getEvents().get(finalEventPosition).stopStopWatch();
                athlete.getEvents().get(finalEventPosition).setIsRunning(false);
            }
        });
        viewHolderItem.btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e("", "Reset Button Clicked!");
                athlete.getEvents().get(finalEventPosition).resetStopWatch();
                athlete.getEvents().get(finalEventPosition).setIsRunning(false);
            }
        });
        // If you click the Save button, it sends total time and splits to the database.
        viewHolderItem.btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()     {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e("", "Save Button Clicked!");

            }
        });

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating Android Listview Constantly but Retain onClick functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635722/updating-android-listview-constantly-but-retain-onclick-functionality)

Answer (score 0):

Just use some Flags for stop refreshing. In your example something like this.
This code should work. (For setting OnClickListener for button in Adapter use interfaces)

```
public bolean isWork = true;

....

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(runnable);

}
Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (isWork) {
          adapterWhiteMales.notifyDataSetChanged();
          handler.postDelayed(runnable, 250);
        }
    }
};

....

myButton.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener () {
   void OnClick () {
       isWork = false;
   }

});
```

Comment: This doesn't work because if I have the same problem as before. If the app is working/refreshing, I still have the same problem of it being slow to click. I need a solution where the list is always refreshing and the buttons are separate.